# SMTP Sender Certificate Issue

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I'm using Mirth Connect 3.4.2.8129.  I'm trying to get an SMTP Sender to work, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
SMTP Sender error
ERROR MESSAGE: Error sending email message
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp10.phimail-dev.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1401)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1428)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.smtp.SmtpDispatcher.send(SmtpDispatcher.java:248)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationConnector.handleSend(DestinationConnector.java:822)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationConnector.process(DestinationConnector.java:476)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationChain.doCall(DestinationChain.java:121)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationChain.call(DestinationChain.java:63)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.process(Channel.java:1715)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.dispatchRawMessage(Channel.java:1198)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.dispatchRawMessage(SourceConnector.java:192)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.DonkeyEngineController.dispatchRawMessage(DonkeyEngineController.java:1053)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.DonkeyMessageController.reprocessMessages(DonkeyMessageController.java:442)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.api.servlets.MessageServlet$3.run(MessageServlet.java:208)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1391)
```

I have installed the certificate provided be the destination that I'm sending to in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\security\cacerts.  I have also created a simple java app that uses the same settings and properties and sends a message successfully.

It seems that Mirth is using a different truststore, but from what I've read 3.1+ uses the default.  There isn't a truststore.jks in the C:\Program Files\Mirth Connect\appdata directory.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 1):

For Mirth community version (without ssl plugin) :

Try using Java trust store. You can manage the certs directly in JAVA.

Path  \lib\security\cacerts 
(Example : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\security\cacerts)

FYI : Mirth keystore will be in keystore.jks under appdata 
(Ex: C:\Program Files\Mirth Connect 342\appdata)